# AngularJS - Unable bind vraiable which name is stored inside another variable with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, multi-level

Binding variable name having in another avriable at one level is working , but not working with multilevel object. below is example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("stageController", stageController);
function stageController($scope) {
    $scope.model = 'realModel';
    $scope.notmodel = 'realModel.innerRealModel';
    $scope.vars = {};    // variables container
    $scope.vars.realModel ="this is working";
    $scope.vars.realModelNot = {};
    $scope.vars.realModelNot.innerRealModel = 'this is not working';
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="stageController">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate="">
        <input type="text" name="myText" ng-model="vars[model]" />
        <input type="text" name="myText2" ng-model="vars[notmodel]" />
    </form>
    <p>Textbox1 : {{vars.realModel}}<p>
    <p>Textbox2 : {{vars.realModelNot.innerRealModel}}<p>
</body>
```

Please let me know to do this with out using any dircetives.

Comment: What is the real world reason you need to do this?   You can't use the bracket notation in this way;  it' isn't a substitution model, it is literally a property string name.  there is no property `'realModelNot.innerRealModel'`, there is a property  `'realModelNot'` which is an object with `'innerRealModel'` as a different property.  i.e. the property you actually want is `vars['realModelNot']['innerRealModel']`, which is very difficult to build from a string template

Comment: Thanks @Claies for you reply.  $scope.notmodel = 'realModel.innerRealModel' I just hard coded this here but actually it is configuarable value and delaing with quite big object so made it configurable

Comment: configurable by *who??*  it seems like you are trying to take a lot of effort to not bind directly to the original model, but it's not really clear why.  If this is for other programmers, that's a pretty hefty amount of work for a small amount of productivity improvement.  If it is so that your end users can specify properties, that's pretty foolhardy as well, since generally end users shouldn't have to/don't care about the properties your forms use, and the ones that are technical enough to are the ones you don't really want hacking with your website and accessing your data.

Comment: Actually having two different objects , one is rendering UI controls let say it is $scope.model  and having around 50 fileds ,configured in xml file.  after binding this to UI need to collect the data in second object(realModelNot.innerRealModel) which is configured in the 1st object

Comment: it seems like you are trying to do something simillar to [schemaform](http://schemaform.io/).  You might be able to look through their code and get some ideas on how they handle complex objects, or just use their project

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the paths you're attempting to use. The first level works because you're doing

```
$scope.model = 'realModel';  // so your template will change vars[model] 
                             // to vars['realModel']
```

but for the second level, you're doing

```
$scope.notmodel = 'realModel.innerRealModel'; // so your template will bind to
                                              // vars['realmodel.innerRealModel']
                                              // and you want vars['realmodel']['innerRealModel']
```

Additionally, if you are binding to `vars.realModel` with a string input field, it will no longer be capable of holding object properties like `innerRealModel`

Comment: $scope.notmodel = 'realModel.innerRealModel' is configuarable value , not sure what object will come  so I can't vars['realmodel']['innerRealModel'] directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing something like vars[realModel.innerRealModel], what doesn't work. For doing something like that you would need to do:

```
vars[realModelNot][innerRealModel]
```

Another question, why just not using directly the scope? Why creating another scope properties to store the name of the properties you want to access?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="stageController">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate="">
      <input type="text" name="myText" ng-model="vars.realModel" />
      <input type="text" name="myText2" ng-model="vars.realModelNot.innerRealModel" />
    </form>
    <p>Textbox1 : {{vars.realModel}}<p>
    <p>Textbox2 : {{vars.realModelNot.innerRealModel}}<p>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function stageController($scope) {
    $scope.vars = {};    // variables container
    $scope.vars.realModel ="this is working";
    $scope.vars.realModelNot = {};
    $scope.vars.realModelNot.innerRealModel = 'this is not working';
}
</script>
```